# Attachment without filename

Tags: c#, email

When using the System.Net.Mail namespace to send a e-mail with attachment to any Yahoo account the attachment is downloaded with 'untitled' name instead the file name.

In the Yahoo Mail interface the attachment looks with the correct name but when you download it the download name goes to 'untitled' for all attachments. The same e-mail message works fine with Gmail, Outlook.com, Windows Live Mail and other clients.

Looking the raw message it constains a content-type with name but without filename attribute. The Yahoo works fine if the filename attribute is set but C# library don't use this.

That's the header generated by C# for attachments:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=test.pdf
```

That's the header that works with Yahoo:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=file2; filename=test.pdf
```

Anyone get this problem so far? Is there a work arround for C# default mail sending?

```
 using (var message = new MailMessage("from@domain", "to@yahoo.com.br", "Test with attachment", "Test with attachment"))
    {
        var attachment = new Attachment(@"c:\temp\test.pdf"); // Same result using stream instead path to file.
        attachment.Name = "test.pdf"; // Same result without this line.
        message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.domain", 587))
        {
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("from@domain", "password");
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the Name property of the attachment?  Can you show us your code?

Comment: Yes, I tried set the file name, sending as stream and passing a path for file. I will put the code to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:

```
attachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = "test.pdf";
```

This add the missing filename attribute in the raw e-mail message and solve the Yahoo limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly specifying the content type?

```
var attachment = new Attachment(... , MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried setting media types also. The download works fine (not corrupted). The only problem is the file name and only with Yahoo accounts.